# What does 'combed back from peak' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[image: Source]

I could not interpret this sentence properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *prominent* widow's peak, the *V* shaped part of his hairline.
[image]

It is "prominent" because it "dives" down his forehead. In other words, his hair line comes down a lot and forms a pronounced peak.

This is *not* a prominent window's peak; it does not dive.
[image]

*Combed back* refers to *combing your hair* to the back of your head

> [comb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comb)
>   : to smooth, arrange, or separate (hair or fibers) with a comb

So as you can see in the first picture, he has his diving widow's peak *combed back* and to his left.

---

> a judge with a grey thatch combed back from a diving widow's peak

In other words, this judge has a grey thatch. How was this thatch formed? It was a thatch that was *combed back* from a diving widow's peak. I think "from a diving widow's peak" implies that the base of his thatch is a diving widow's peak.

Yes, you can also say "combed back from *his* diving widow's peak". It is clear from context that it was his own hair, his own widow's peak. That is why combed back from *a* diving widow's peak works too.

Comment: So diving is a synonym for prominent?

Comment: I reworded my post.

Comment: 'combed from a prominent window's peak' seems weird.Should it be 'from his' or 'to his'?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Ok, I have updated my answer. Please ask for any clarification.